# SQL: Update a table column with data in column retrieved from a view in same procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, select, stored-procedures, sql-update

I'm trying to do a select and update within the same local procedure. The idea is to retrieve
the number of ordered products from a specific order in the view (Produktantal) and then updating the stock numbers (antal) from the table "produktlager" with the data retrieved from the view.

I'm receiving the follow error message `Error: ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'Produktantal' in 'field list'`. I don't seem to be available to access the column in the update part. How can I do this?

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS update_stock_status;
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE PROCEDURE update_stock_status(
    p_orderid INT
)
BEGIN
    SELECT 
    Produktid,
    Orderid,
    Produktantal,
    Lagerantal,
    Hylla
    FROM v_products2order_w_products2lager
    WHERE Orderid = p_orderid;

    UPDATE produkt2lager
    SET
        antal = antal - Produktantal
    WHERE
        produktid = Produktid
    AND
        hylla = Hylla;
END
;;
DELIMITER ;
```

The view:

```
    DROP VIEW IF EXISTS v_products2order_w_products2lager;

    CREATE VIEW v_products2order_w_products2lager AS
    SELECT
        p2o.produktid AS "Produktid",
        p2o.orderid AS "Orderid",
        p2o.antal AS "Produktantal",
        p2l.antal AS "Lagerantal",
        p2l.hylla AS "Hylla"
    FROM
        produkt2order AS p2o
        LEFT OUTER JOIN produkt2lager AS p2l ON p2o.produktid = p2l.produktid;
```

Comment: Sample data and desire results would help.  Your code does nothing useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two statements in your procedure are executed independently, and the second statement cannot in any way access the results of the first one.

I suspect that you want the `update ... join` syntax:

```
UPDATE produkt2lager p
INNER JOIN v_products2order_w_products2lager o 
    ON o.produktid = p.produktid
    AND o.hylla = p.hylla
SET p.antal = p.antal - o.produktantal
WHERE o.oderid = p_order_id
```

Comment: I just had to rewrite it slightly to work with my version of MYSQL. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think you want an `UPDATE` with a `JOIN`:

```
UPDATE produkt2lager l
       v_products2order_w_products2lager v
       ON l.produktid = v.produktid and
          l.hylla = v.hylla
    SET l.antal = l.antal - v.Produktantal;
```